# Checking word in text file

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

Hi I'm creating an anti link spam bot for Discord and I'm trying to delete a message that has certain keywords/urls in it.

A list of keywords are saved in a separate file called **/banned_words.json** and I'm wanting the bot to read from that file when a keyword is detected in a message and delete that message.

Here is a snippet of code I'm working with, I'm struggling with this line of code `if word in word_set:` so an example of how to define `word` would be appreciated.

```
def __init__(self, bot):
    self.bot = bot
    self.bannedwords = dataIO.load_json('data/spamfilter/banned_words.json')

async def banned_words(self, message):
    word = word in line.split():
    word_set = set(self.bannedwords)
    if word in word_set:
        await self.bot.delete_message(message)
        msg = await self.bot.send_message(
            message.channel,
            "{}, **Avertisement is not allowed on this server.**".format(
                message.author.mention
            )
        )
        await asyncio.sleep(6)
        await self.bot.delete_message(msg)
        return
```

Comment: word_set  is defined as the json file containing the words.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I would set this up, using the built-in [`any`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any) function:

```
class MyCog:
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot
        self.bannedwords = set(dataIO.load_json('data/spamfilter/banned_words.json'))

    async def banned_words(self, message):
        words = set(message.content.split())
        word_set = self.bannedwords
        if any(word in word_set for word in words):
            await self.bot.delete_message(message)
            msg = await self.bot.send_message(
                message.channel,
                "{}, **Avertisement is not allowed on this server.**".format(
                    message.author.mention
                )
            )
            await asyncio.sleep(6)
            await self.bot.delete_message(msg)
```

Comment: I have a question how would you for  delete a message contains an extension of words for example: "hellothere" rather than "hello there"  or a link for example 
if the banned word is example.com a person posts something like  example.com/hello  it was to delete?

Comment: @DaveHonley You could do a simple membership check for the substring `any(word in message.content for word in word_set)`, but that will also catch innocent substrings.  If you want to ban the word "sword", this would also catch "swordfish" and "password".  That's a non-trivial problem, and probably involves some degree of natural language processing and fuzzy string matching.

Answer (score 0):

This line is completely wrong:

```
word = word in line.split():
```

First, there is an extraneous colon at the end. Second, `x in y` yields a boolean which represents whether or not `x` is in `y`.

You're going to have to iterate through all the words in the message, and perform the check for each one:

```
word_set = set(self.bannedwords)
for word in line.split():
    if word in word_set:
```

Comment: `for word in line.split()` seems to be the wrong usage I'm attempting to read the words in .json here is how I have implemented your reply. 

` word_set = set(self.bannedwords)
        for word in word_set:
            if word in message.content:
                return
            
            await self.bot.delete_message(message)`

However this would delete any work I put is so maybe it should be defining something?

Comment: What is it you want to do? Check if any words from the file are in the message, or check if any words from the message are in the file?

Comment: Check if any words from the file are in the message